# How to setup Doctrine 2 for php project?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to set up 'PartKeepr', but keep getting the error at the prerequisites:

> Doctrine needs to be installed and in the PHP include_path.
>
> Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader was not found

I have installed Doctrine through Composer in C drive

[image: Screenshot]

I did include_path in php.ini file but didn't work.
What path i have to include and how to resolve the issue?
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search, I came to know that we cannot run partkeepr directly on windows. We have to use Virtual Machine Image. And secondly we have to install doctrine2 through pear and not composer.

Comment: Yes, that is true that you cannot run PartKeepr due to filename colissions (currently, there's a partkeepr.js and a PartKeepr.js). It is being worked on to make PartKeepr run on Windows as well.